# In how many ways can a student select $4$ out of $20$ recommended books if exactly $3$ of the $12$ recommended physics books are selected?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Here's the question.

A student is selecting $4$ out of $20$ recommended books for a certain course. Twelve are physics books. How many of these selections have exactly $3$ of the $12$ physics books?

Here's my set up.

$$\binom{20}{4}\binom{12}{8}$$

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: No.  $\binom{8}{12} = 0$.

Comment: ${8 \choose 12}=0$, so no.  ${20 \choose 4}$ is the total number of ways of choosing books, so is not relevant to the question.

Comment: oops i ment to say(20 choose 4) X (12 choose 8). will this help me get my answer?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit the question itself rather than placing your corrections in the comments, where they may be missed.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  I do not understand your answer.  $\binom{20}{4}$ is the number of ways of selecting $4$ of the $20$ books.   I am not sure what $\binom{12}{8}$ is meant to count.  What you want to count is the number of ways of selecting $3$ of the $12$ physics books and $1$ of the other $8$ books.

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvotes.  This person met the criteria - asked a reasonable question, presented some initial work, made revisions.  Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Work to your constraints first.  You are required to have only combinations that have three physics books in them: start with that; how many ways are there to choose three physics books?

Now, for each combination of 3 physics books, you have to choose a non-physics book.  (Why?  Because the question says "exactly" three physics books.  If it said "at least three," then you need a different strategy.)  How many non-physics books are there?

Pair the "how many ways to choose a single non-physics book" with each unique combination of "how many ways to pick three physics books" and you get your answer.